# Select values from two mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

I have two tables called `Job` and `Bid` . customer can add job details and multiple suppliers can bid for the job.Once customer select one supplier from bids,that supplier id (sId) will update on `Job` table. i want to select job details with bid value.

This is what i tried

```
SELECT job.id,job.title,job.desc,job.mobile,job.address, job.city,job.updatedAt,job.status,bid.value,customer.cName,supplier.sName
FROM job
LEFT JOIN customer 
     ON customer.id = job.cId 
LEFT JOIN supplier 
     ON supplier.id = job.sId
LEFT JOIN bid 
     ON bid.sId = job.sId`
```

but this query showing messy information with some duplicates

**`job` Table** 
[image]

**`bid` table**
[image]

There are two suppliers (sId=2 and sId=1) has bid for job no 5 (i have marked on `bid` table).but customer has pick sId 2 for the job number 5.now i want to select from those tables without messy records.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are just missing a join condition on bid, that filters on the chosen supplier. The logic to allow jobs without a supplier yet while evicting jobs whose supplier was not picked by the customer is a bit tricky, and is implemented in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT ...
FROM job
INNER JOIN customer 
      ON customer.id = job.cId 
LEFT JOIN supplier 
      ON supplier.id = job.sId
LEFT JOIN bid 
     ON  bid.sId = job.sId 
     AND bid.jId = job.id   --> here
WHERE supplier.id IS NULL OR bid.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @CMB Thanks.your query did good.but it's not showing records for job number 8 and 9.i want to show jobs ,that still haven't assign for any supplier (with sId `null` records).

Comment: @Tje123: I think I see what you mean. I modified the query a little.

Answer (score 1):

in your select statment you tring to retrive data from bid table `bid.value` but you didn't join that table.

```
select j.id,
       j.title,
       j.desc,
       j.mobile,
       j.address,
       j.city,
       j.updatedAt,
       j.status,
       b.value,
       c.cName,
       s.sName
from job as j
         inner join customer as c
                    on j.cId = c.id
         inner join supplier as s
                    on j.sId = s.id
         inner join bid as b
                    on j.id = b.jId;
```